# Binding the content of a ListBoxItem to something not related to

Tags: wpf, mvvm, listboxitem

I'm new to WPF, but am pretty familiar with binding list box controls to observable collections in the view model.

In my current project we have a ListBox that is used for navigating to different pages in a frame box.  I want to add some display information to the first ListBoxItem to show which object (in this case, the Scenario) is being worked on (it is selected in a previous frame that visible in the subsequent frames).  The ListBox itself is using a static list defined in the xaml, so it isn't bound to anything in the ViewModel.  The CurrentScenario is a property on the ViewModel.  I was able to add a Label to the same window that contains this ListBox and successfully bind CurrentScenario.Id to its content, and it updated correctly, so I know that the path in the Binding statement should resolve correctly.

```
<ListBox  
  Style="{StaticResource FunctionBackground}" 
  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
>
    <ListBoxItem Style="{StaticResource FunctionListBoxItemStyle}">
        <ListBoxItem.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Scenario" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=CurrentScenario.Id}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBoxItem.ContentTemplate>
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Style="{StaticResource FunctionListBoxItemStyle}" >Parameter</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Style="{StaticResource FunctionListBoxItemStyle}" >Run</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Style="{StaticResource FunctionListBoxItemStyle}" >Results</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

When I try to add this extra information to the listbox item, from what I can tell, the list box item has an empty text block below the text block with the word "Scenario." I can't figure out why the empty text box content is not showing the value of the bound property.  When I put a normal string in the Text property of the second text block, it shows up correctly.

I imagine that either ListBoxItem content is only set up be bound to properties related to the ItemSource, and so it ignores attempts to bind to other things, or maybe there is something fundamental in WPF that I am missing.  Or both...

Thanks if anyone has any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if property `CurrentScenario` is in ViewModel you can use `RelativeSource` to binding to this property.

```
...
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Scenario" />
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.CurrentScenario.Id, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"/>
...
```

Comment: That worked exactly as you have it.  Thanks!
One more question, do I need to put in this extra plumbing because WPF needs extra direction for the ListBoxItem since I'm not using it in the traditional way?  I really expected it to work the way I had it, I'd just like to understand it better.

Thanks again!